# How to iterate through list of list of dictionaries?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

> A graph query results in a list of list of dictionaries. How can I iterate through the dictionaries?

**My entry data looks like:**

```
my_list = [[{'name': 'John', 'id': 4, 'label': ['person']}, {'name': 'Peter', 'id': 20, 'label': ['bot']}, {'name': 'Lili', 'id': 24, 'label': ['person']}]]
```

**I tried:**

`my_new_list = [x[0] for x in my_list]`

However, it just results in another list with a single dictionary inside - the first one:

```
[{'name': 'John', 'id': 4, 'label': ['person']}, {'name': 'Peter', 'id':20, 'label': ['bot']}, {'name': 'Lili', 'id': 24, 'label': ['person']}]
```

My ultimate goal is to iterate through the dictionaries and conditionally append keys and values (`'image': image_source`) depending on the label.
I would like to receive just a list of dictionaries that can be iterated and not a list of list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a nested list, the first element is just another list. So you need to iterate through that one instead. You

`my_new_list = [x for x in my_list[0]]`

But that's the same as just setting `my_new_list` as the first element in `my_list`:

```
my_new_list = my_list[0]
my_other_new_list = [x for x in my_list[0]]
my_new_list == my_other_new_list # True
```

You can then iterate through `my_new_list` to access all the dicts in the list.

```
everyone_named_john = [x for x in my_list[0] if x['name'] == 'John']
everyone_named_john = [x for x in my_new_list if x['name'] == 'John']
```